# Does "respectively" come before or after what it describes?

Tags: sentence-construction, syntax

I have the following construction:

> If union and intersection of A and B sets *are* defined **respectively** as
>   *A U B :=(Va U Vb), A ^ B :=(Va ^ Vb)*, . Where Va and Vb are points within the each entity.

if we describe many things in a certain order, then we could use the word *respectively*. As far as I know, *respectively* comes after describing those objects. But, in my case it comes before the description. So I want to know whether this is a correct or not.

Comment: I usually see the word _respectively_ at the end, but it doesn't **need** to go at the end. In your example, I'd recommend putting it **before** all the formal math symbols, so I'd leave it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would venture to say that prefixing the items with the word "respectively" is grammatical, but just not idiomatic. A much more natural way of saying your sentence would be:

> If **[the]** union and intersection of **[the sets]** A and B [-*sets*-] are defined as A U B :=(Va U Vb), A ^ B :=(Va ^ Vb) **respectively**, ...

Note that for mathematical texts, I would normally put the caveats in brackets (see below). Even if you don't. you need to use commas because "where X is blah" is a appositive clause, not a sentence:

> ... as A U B :=(Va U Vb), A ^ B :=(Va ^ Vb) (*where Va and Vb are points within the each entity*).
>
> ... as A U B :=(Va U Vb), A ^ B :=(Va ^ Vb), where Va and Vb are points within the each entity, ...

and you also need to properly close off your sentence with a *then* clause, since you opened with an **if**. Suppose the conclusion is that F=Y; then you could use the following sentence:

> If the union and intersection of the sets A and B are defined as A U B :=(Va U Vb), A ^ B :=(Va ^ Vb) respectively, (where Va and Vb are points within A and B respectively), then F=Y.

Answer (score 3):

It is more common for *respectively* to come after what it describes, but either is correct. Your example uses *respectively* correctly (though the last sentence is a fragment).